# Add Data to Core Data from Array Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

If I have an array of data for instance:

```
let  array = ["73", "24", "12", "62", "42"]
```

And I would like to loop through the array and add its number to my entity called Device with attribute asset_tag and then print out the values from my core data stack.

Currently my code is as follows:

```
 var data: [String] = ["53","35","26","42","12"]

   let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

        let task = Device(context: context)

        task.asset_tag = data


        (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()


        do {
            data = try context.fetch(Device.fetchRequest())
        }

        catch {
            print ("This did not work")
        }


        print (data)
```

but it doesn't look like you can just add an array as the source for data into an attribute.

Comment: Do you want to create 5 devices with one attribute respectively or 1 device ? Anyway the array is an array of strings, why do you annotate it as most unspecified `[Any]`?

Comment: I would like to enter 5 devices, each device would be a different asset tag number.

Comment: Then no, you can't do it this way. You need a repeat loop to create the 5 devices.

Comment: `Device(context: context)` is a custom method. I have no idea what it does exactly. Otherwise (pseudocode) : `for tag in data { let device = create_the_device(); device.asset_tag =  tag } save_the_context()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spent some time and finally figured it out. Code is as follows:

```
for device in data {

            let newArray = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Device", into: context)

            newArray.setValue(device, forKey: "asset_tag")
        }
```